# How to define a subformula of an inductively defined type in Agda?

Tags: types, agda, type-theory, decidable

I'm trying to define a simple predicate to determine if a formula is a subformula of a given formal over a simple inductively defined syntax.  I'm running into a few, presumably simple, problems.

(i) I'd rather use a parameterized module with a given type A.  How can one import the information that A is a set, in the sense that A has decideable equality?  If this can't be done, what are some workarounds?  This is why I have Nat instead.

(ii) Is the `t1 ≡ (t2 // t3)` (and similairly defined) predicates `isSubFormula` the proper way to deal with equal subformulas?  If not, how else does one easily do this?  I've also considered writing a predicate for `equalFmla` and then making a global subformula predicate with `isSubFormula ⊎ equalFmla` but am not sure if this is so clean.

(iii) Why do the last three lines highlight blue when I pattern match internal to the first one?  How can I fix this

(iv) Why won't the `{!Data.Nat._≟_ n1 n2 !}` refine below?

```
module categorial1 (A : Set) where

open import Data.Nat using (ℕ)
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Sum
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

-- type symbols
data tSymb : Set where
  -- base : A → tSymb
  base : ℕ → tSymb
  ~ : tSymb → tSymb
  _\\_ : tSymb → tSymb → tSymb
  _//_ : tSymb → tSymb → tSymb

-- A needs a decideable notion of equality
isSubFormula : tSymb → tSymb → Set
-- isSubFormula y (base x) = {!!}
isSubFormula (base n1) (base n2) = {!Data.Nat._≟_ n1 n2 !}
isSubFormula (~ t1) (base x) = ⊥
isSubFormula (t1 \\ t2) (base x) = ⊥
isSubFormula (t1 // t2) (base x) = ⊥
isSubFormula t1 (~ t2) = t1 ≡ (~ t2) ⊎ isSubFormula t1 t2
isSubFormula t1 (t2 \\ t3) = t1 ≡ (t2 \\ t3) ⊎ isSubFormula t1 t2 ⊎ isSubFormula t1 t3
isSubFormula t1 (t2 // t3) = t1 ≡ (t2 // t3) ⊎ isSubFormula t1 t2 ⊎ isSubFormula t1 t3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite a lot of different questions; Stack Overflow works better if you post each question separately.

Nevertheless, here are some answers:

> (i) I'd rather use a parameterized module with a given type A. How can
> one import the information that A is a set, in the sense that A has
> decideable equality?

You can parametrize your module by the decision procedure, i.e. something like this:

```
open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

module categorical1 {A : Set} (_≟_ : Decidable (_≡_ {A = A})) where
```

Note that we import `Relation.Binary` (for `Decidable`) and `R.B.PropositionalEquality` (for `_≡_`) *before* the module header, since the parameter types of our module depend on these definitions.

> (iii) Why do the last three lines highlight blue when I pattern match
> internal to the first one? How can I fix this

This is Agda warning you that those clauses won't hold definitionally, because they depend on the previous clauses not matching on `t1`.

> (iv) Why won't the {!Data.Nat.*≟* n1 n2 !} refine below?

Because `isSubFormula` returns a `Set`, but `n1 ≟ n2` returns a `Dec _≡_`.

I think there is confusion in your code about whether `isSubFormula` is supposed to be a proposition or a decision procedure. If it returns a `Set`, it means it is a proposition. You can write that without decidable equality since there is nothing to decide -- `isSubFormula`-ness of two `base` values means they are equal:

```
isSubFormula : tSymb → tSymb → Set
isSubFormula (base n1) (base n2) = n1 ≡ n2
```

If you want a decision procedure, you could do it "boolean-blindly" by instead writing `isSubFormula : tSymb → tSymb → Bool`, or by keeping `isSubFormula` as a proposition and writing `decSubFormula : Decidable isSubFormula`.

Note also that you only need decidable equality on `A` if you are trying to decide `isSubFormula`, so you can do

```
module categorical1 (A : Set) where

... 

isSubFormula : tSymb → tSymb → Set

decSubFormula : Decidable (_≡_ {A = A}) → Decidable isSubFormula
decSubFormula _≟A_ = ? -- You can use _≟A_ here to decide equality of A values
```